# Com Port Mapping - Azure IOT Edge - Windows IOT 2019

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have an edge device (Welotec MK3) with on board Serial ports that I would like to access Modbus RTU devices with. Issue resides in the proper configuration of the Container Create Options - thus in mapping the physical to the containers com port.

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "Devices": [
      {
        "PathOnHost": "COM2",
        "PathInContainer": "COM2",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Physical com port is identified in Window 2019 IOT as COM2, but IOT Edge s throwing an error indicating improper mapping.

Hoping someone has come across this and can provide some guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The deployment syntax for device access uses PathInContainer:"" and PathOnHost="class/<device interface guid>".  The device interface guid for serial is 86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73. note also that this only works with --isolation process.  see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/hardware-devices-in-containers) for more info.
The best way to refer to the device in your container app depends on the language you're writing in and container OS you're using.